# "Merging" two nested arrays

Tags: python, python-3.x

To put it briefly, I'm making a program where a user can add a recipe, and I'm having an issue with this code which comes with:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices not list
```

```
for things in ingredients:
   recipe.append(ingredients[things])
```

In this instance, recipe would look something like this:

```
recipe = [["name", "cake"], ["amount", 2]]
```

And ingredients would be

```
[["eggs", 12], ["flour", 500]]
```

What I'm trying to do is just add each nested array from "ingredients" to "recipe" and this is just the simplest thing I could come up with - I know how I could do this differently with dictionaries or a while loop, but I'd just like to know why this brings up an error.

Comment: Add `print(things)` before `append`ing and see if `ingredients[things]` makes any sense

Comment: I think this change in the `for` loop might work - `recipe.append(things)`

Comment: did you try `recipe.extend(ingredients)` without the loop ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Sajan suggested in the comments, you have to change your `.append` syntax.
If you want to iterate through the list's content:

```
for things in ingredients:
   recipe.append(things)
```

If you want to iterate through the list's indexes:

```
for index in range(len(ingredients)):
   recipe.append(ingredients[index])
```

The results will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you're trying to pass an array as an index for the ingredients array.

Which will not work and cause the exception TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices not list, telling you that you can't slice an array using array. (https://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-slices.html)

```
for things in ingredients:
   # things == ["eggs", 12] in the first iteration of the loop
   # and ["flour", 500] in the second, so you can't use ["eggs", 12] or ["flour", 500] as an array index.
   recipe.append(things)
```

So if you want to use index you will need to loop on range of the Length of ingredients array.

```
for i in range(len(ingredients)):
   recipe.append(ingredients[i])
```